# Solve the special congreuences equation?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

the following congruencies

$\begin{matrix}
x_1\equiv1~(\mod m_1)\\
x_2\equiv1~(\mod m_2)\\
\vdots\\
x_n\equiv1~(\mod m_n)\\
\end{matrix}$

where $m_i, m_j(i\neq j)$ are pairwise coprime.
Now, I known the value of $x_i(i=1~\text{to}~n)$ and $s = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n m_i$. Any algorithm can calclute the value of $m_i(i=1~\text{to}~n)$?
The value of $m$ and $x_i$ may be vary large.

example:

$\begin{matrix}
2338762918 \equiv 1~(\mod m_1)\\
1299869595 \equiv 1~(\mod m_2)
\end{matrix}$
and $m_1\times m_2=99221$, the answer $m_1=317, m_2=313$.
But this $m_i$ and $s$ is too small, many algorithms can do this.

---

I have found the method to solve this problem with the help of @Math Gems. Tks very much.

The useful Corollary described as follow. The original problem had ignore a important condition $\gcd(x_i-1,s/m_i)=1$ for $i=1$ to $n$.

Assume that $\{m_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are n pairwise coprime positive integers, $s = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n m_i$, $x_i\equiv 1\pmod{m_i}$. If $\gcd(x_i-1,s/m_i)=1$, then
$m_i=\gcd(x_i,s)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\:(x_i\!-\!1)/m_i\:$ is coprime to the other moduli then you can recover the moduli $\rm\: m_i\:$ by taking gcds, e.g. in your example
$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm gcd(2338762918\!-\!1,99221)\!\! &=& 317\\ \rm gcd(1299869595\!-\!1,99221)\!\! &=& 313\end{eqnarray}$$

If that does not hold true, then the problem may require factorization, e.g. in the worst case $\rm\:x_i = 1+ m_1\cdots m_n\:$ which yields no gcd splittings of $\rm\: s = m_1\cdots m_m,\:$ so the problem reduces to factoring $\rm\:s.$

Comment: but when the numbers go large, there would be many possible combinations. How do you know which one will work?

Comment: Such combinatorics seems inherent in the problem, e.g. if $\rm\:x_i = 1 + m_1\cdots m_n\:$ then it reduces to a pure factoring problem. On the other extreme, if $\rm\: (x_i\!-\!1)/m_i\:$ is coprime to the other moduli, then gcds immediately yield the $\rm\:m_i.\ $

Comment: @Easy But it is if you want to find *all* solutions.

Comment: the problem is if you find a possible combination $(m_1,\cdots,m_n)$ from $x_1-1$, this combination might not satisfy $m_2|x_2-1$, etc...

Comment: @Easy I don't see why you think that is related to what I wrote.

Comment: @MathGems  Integer factoring the complexity may too large? If $s$ is $10^{200}$...

Comment: @Yuanshengliu Factorization is unavoidable since special cases of your problem reduce to it - as I remarked. Any algorithm that solves the general case of your problem can also be used to factor any integer.

Comment: @MathGems I had known. Tks very much.